# How to integrate further JS dependencies in ZURB FOUNDATION project?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the ZURB Template (ZURB foundation 6.4). 
I want to use dropdown menus and the like, which require the integration of further JS dependencies.
Here is the official Documentation:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html

The following is important for me:

The following files must be included in your JavaScript to use this plugin:

```
foundation.core.js
foundation.dropdownMenu.js
    With utility library foundation.util.keyboard.js
    With utility library foundation.util.box.js
    With utility library foundation.util.nest.js
    With utility library foundation.util.touch.js
```

Now I dont really know where I have to do these inclusions, and how. 
I already integrated a third party plugin into my project, chart.js, but this is obviously a "native" plugin by foundation and I dont know how to do this. 
In which file do I have to make these additions, and with what syntax? 
In the app.js, they already use a mixture of ES6 and CommonJS for getting Jquery to run, because the hoisting behavior of ES6 would cause problems. 
However, this doesn't really make things easier for me and it makes me wonder even more what I have to do to set this up ^^

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/src/assets/js/app.js and the explicit-pieces file for an example.